# Why do `std::ranges::size` require a non-const method when using ADL?

Tags: c++, c++20, argument-dependent-lookup, std-ranges

> Otherwise, size(t) converted to its decayed type, if ranges::disable_sized_range<std::remove_cv_t<T>> is false, and the converted expression is valid and has an integer-like type, ***where the overload resolution is performed with the following candidates:***
>
> - `void size(auto&) = delete;`
> - `void size(const auto&) = delete;`
>   [1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/size#:%7E:text=where%20the%20overload%20resolution%20is%20performed%20with%20the%20following%20candidates)

```
class Test {
    friend size_t size(/*const*/ Test&) {
        return 0;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::ranges::size(Test{});
    // no matching function error when adding the `const` qualifier
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/79e5vrKrT

---

Generally, `size` method doesn't require to modify the range, [like what `std::size` does](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size).

Why is there such a constraint of `std::ranges::size`? (Seems it's only performed for non-member version.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is there such a constraint of `std::ranges::size`? (Seems it's only
> performed for non-member version.)

Although the `size` method does not modify the range, some ranges do not have a `const`-qualified member `begin()`, which allows only non-`const`-qualified objects to model a `range`.

This also makes [some range adaptors](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.chunk.view.input) in the standard may only have a non-`const`-qualified `size`.

For your example, considering that `Test` only has non-`const` `begin`/`end` or  `size`, then `friend size_t size(Test&)` can really only be the option.

Comment: But it's surprising that `friend size_t size(const Test&)` doesn't work for both const and non-const objects. It only doesn't work for both because of the`void size(auto&) = delete;` overload, if that is removed from the implementation, then it works.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Agree. This seems more like a standard defect to me.

Comment: We had [LWG 3480](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3480), which is also based on these poison pills, which we resolved by changing the non-member functions -- but that one could've also been resolved by changing the poison pills.

Comment: Hum, I think removing this non-`const` size poison pill would be a more appropriate solution here since I don't see any observable reasonable harm from removing it.